# setting attributes outside of class

Tags: python, class, attributes

so I have a class,

```
class Interval:  
    def __init__(self, min, max):
        self.min = min 
        self.max = max
        self.compare_mode = None 

    def min_max(min, max = None)-> 'Interval Object':
        '''Code to return properly initialized Interval Object
        '''
        ...
        return Interval(min, max)
```

this is just the main parts of my class for my questions. Here I have two properly initialized Interval objects

```
l = Interval.min_max(1.0,5.0)
r = Interval.min_max(4.0,6.0)
```

now I am trying to just update the class' self.compare_mode attribute by just binding certain strings to it with the following code:

```
Interval.compare_mode = 'liberal'
```

now when I print out the value from outside the class using `print(Interval.compare_mode)`
it looks like the value is bounded but when I try access this string from other methods within my Interval class it still initialed to None. I just want to update the class' compare_mode attribute after the Interval objects are created using `Interval.compare_mode = 'some string'` at any point this code is initiated.

Comment: That code can't work as it is. Are you sure `min_max` is not a staticmethod?

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the instance attribute and class' attributes.

When you assign to `self.compare_mode` you are referring to the instance attribute, when you assign `Interval.compare_mode` you refer to the class attribute.

However when reading, first it tries to give you an instance attribute, then if that fails you get the class attribute.

Try this modification:

```
class Interval:
    compare_mode = None # Class attribute

    def __init__(self, min, max):
        self.min = min 
        self.max = max
        # NOT setting self.compare_mode here
```